# create an object

Tags: java, android

how can i create an object so i can get the item. 
i found an example that said

```
    Object item2 = getListView().getAdapter().getItem(holder.position);
```

to create the object but thing is different in my class 
can you help me to find how
cause i need the object

here is my class. how can i do it here:

i need the object to do some functions.

Comment: This is ambiguous, which object do you want? Do you want one of the HashMap objects stored in the adapter?

Comment: Since you are working with an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` you should consider using or extending [`SimpleAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html).

Comment: @sam you mean that i remove extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//if you have an instance of the adapter...
int index = 5;  //or whatever index you want
HashMap<String,String> mHashMap = adapter.getItem(index);


//if you are inside of the MyCustomAdapter class...
int index = 5;
HashMap<String,String> mHashMap = getItem(index);
```

Comment: how can i get the adapter as they do Object item2 = getListView().getAdapter().getItem(holder.position); even if my adapter isdiffrent type

Comment: That is being called from inside a ListActivity with no reference to the adapter.. is that your situation? If not, there is no need for that. Just a longer way of getting to the same object

Comment: ok i call it in MyCustomAdapter so i can get the oject and remove it student.remove(mHashMap); then notifyDataSetChanged(); should i include it in run thred or not ?